# What's the difference between Alt and AltGr on my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Can anyone please tell me the difference between Alt and AltGr on my keyboard.
I'm just curious to know the difference.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Most programs use ALT to add different functionality to the keys pressed (ALT+F4 closes a program for example)

AltGr is mostly used to enter completely different characters into textboxes (altgr+c=© for example).

So ALT has more to do with functions while AltGr has to do with input.

Comment: Most of the time, <Alt> + <Ctrl> = <AltGr>. For example, the @ can be created via <AltGr> + <Q> or via <Ctrl> + <Alt> + <Q>. (Also works with ©, µ, ~, ², ...) - This is of course only valid for standard QWERTY- (and QWERTZ-)keyboard-layouts.