# Why does the Alt+Space keyboard shorcut not work on Windows 10 to open system menu?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, alt

From Windows 3.1 (probably earlier) all the way to Windows 8.1, when I'm in a program, if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, I get the system menu (the menu popup which has menu items like Restore, Move, Size, Maximize, Minimize).

Now, after 25+ years using Windows, this keystroke is hardwired into my fingers and I found out just now that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't work on Windows 10 Build 1803. I can still show the system menu by clicking on the system menu (top left corner) but I need a keyboard shortcut for times when the title bar is not visible.

Is there a way to enable this behavior for all programs/windows ?

## Update 2:

I noticed that I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> outside of the Chrome scenario. E.g.: Notepad window is too small, so I try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to maximize the window, etc. So, I am really missing the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

## Update 3:

I noticed after updating to version 1903 that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> wasn't still working! I was really annoyed -- but what I noticed was that the <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the right hand side of the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar wasn't doing the trick; however, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the left hand side of the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar worked fine.

This probably worked earlier as well but I've been using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the right hand side for over 25 years and Windows 10 has changed that -- why ? Microsoft why ?

## Update 4:

I see that dell has this issue -- https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln238073/right-alt-click-dosen-t-work?lang=en

So, it's probably not an issue for all computers or computers running a version of Windows 10 --- most likely only for Dell computers.

Comment: I use a bookmarklet from google bookmarks program to bookmark various sites that I visit -- this is similar to del.icio.us. The google bookmarks bookmarklet pops up a window where I can add the relevant tags. The problem is that once in a while, this small popup is positioned in such a way as to move its title bar hidden from view. Earlier, I would use ALT + SPACE to move it to visible area. Now with ALT+SPACE missing, I don't know how to get that window to move to visible area -- I don't want to write a spy program to do this. Anyone ?

Comment: ALT+space works on my windows 10 v1903.

Comment: @LPChip : My build is 1803 (OS build 17134.1006) © 2018 Microsoft. So, it means they have fixed it in a newer build. Which means, it is time to update! Thank you.

Comment: probably some programs on your PC captured that shortcut, because it has always worked on my PCs

Comment: As I mentioned, it has worked more than 26 years -- stopped only now. As @LPChip mentioned, the feature was removed till build no 1903.

Comment: no, I've used Windows 10 for years and never saw it stopped working, so it probably only stopped on your PC

Comment: ***It has never been removed or stopped working. It doesn't relate to MS, Windows or Dell***. It's that **the keyboard layout has been changed to a layout that uses the [AltGr key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)** so the right Alt key has a different function. Please stop blaming them and change the people who change your keyboard layout. Also don't use the right Alt as the Alt meta key

Comment: possible duplicate: [In a windows keyboard, is right ALT treated as AltGr?](https://superuser.com/q/1241733/241386), [What's the difference between Alt and AltGr on my keyboard?](https://superuser.com/q/1225180/241386)

Comment: Unable to reproduce on a Dell 7060 running Win10 1909.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a [Dell laptop/computer issue](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln238073/right-alt-click-dosen-t-work?lang=en)

I don't have a fix for Windows 10 but the above link gives a fix for windows 7.

Windows 10 fix: use <kbd>left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: it's not a Dell issue. If the right Alt key doesn't work then it means you're using a keyboard layout with [AltGr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) which is different from the normal Alt

Comment: change to a different keyboard layout if you really need to use the right Alt

Comment: Please read the Dell link above carefully: *You might come across a problem when the keyboard layout is set to "English US International*. The US International is a layout that uses AltGr, and in all Windows (even Windows 10) the same solution applies: change to US keyboard layout in settings or control panel

Answer (score 13):

For anyone else that stumbles on this page I was getting a search windows that came up when I hit Alt + Spacebar. It turns out this was an on-by-default feature in the new Windows PowerToys utility from Microsoft. You can turn the "PowerToys Run" feature off or change the keyboard shortcut to restore Alt + Spacebar to its former glory.

Comment: this is long long ago, far before the new PowerToys was released, and is just because the OP used AltGr instead of Alt

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/1585769/why-does-the-altspace-keyboard-shorcut-no-longer-work-on-windows-10-to-open-the

Answer (score 2):

As much as we appreciate your nostalgia for the Olden Times of the *Microsoft* *Windows* Version 3.1 Operating System - when things were *really* working -, there is nothing wrong in its Tenth Version in the respect that you have just described.

A Non-*Universal Windows Platform* Static Software Application behaves well in this respect. Check out the following example caught in the *Google* *Chrome* Web-Browser:

[image: Google Chrome Context Menu]

Surprisingly, even an *Universal Windows Platform* Static Software Application still has it. Check out the following example caught in the *Digi.Online* I.P.T.V. Client:

[image: Digi.Online Context Menu]

Now, the funny thing is that we do remember that sometimes these shortcuts seem not to be working for some reason. Either they have been disabled before their build, or there is some other reason.

You must have hit a non-usual case. You should investigate more. Add more detail to your Issue.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I know that the system menu is present. Except the ALT + SPACE key is not activating it. I need a way to activate the system menu. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

It has never stopped working in any Windows versions. It's just that **you didn't press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>** but <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> which is a completely different combo

On Windows [AltGr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key) is treated the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>: [Can I make Ctrl+Alt NOT act like AltGr on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/592970/241386) so <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> produces <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

The default layout on US Windows is *US*. But it's extremely common for people to mistake the *US* and *US International* when setting up a new computer. [US International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#US-International) is a layout that maps <kbd>AltGr</kbd> on the <kbd>right Alt</kbd> key, and in all Windows including Windows 10 the solution is the same: **change to the US keyboard layout** which doesn't have <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (if you don't have any need to type some Western European characters in the US keyboard)

This has **nothing to do with MS, Windows or Dell**. It's you who changed or selected the wrong keyboard layout, so stop blaming them. It's already clear from what you observed

> but what I noticed was that the <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the right hand side of the Space bar wasn't doing the trick; however, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the left hand side of the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar worked fine

It's also explained right from the very first paragraph in the Dell link you provided:

> You might come across a problem when the keyboard layout is set to "English US International"
>
> [Right Alt click does not work in Windows 7](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-vn/000136390/right-alt-click-does-not-work-in-windows-7)

- [In a windows keyboard, is right ALT treated as AltGr?](https://superuser.com/q/1241733/241386)
- [What's the difference between Alt and AltGr on my keyboard?](https://superuser.com/q/1225180/241386)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around it by opening PowerToys Settings > PowerToys Run and just changing the *Open PowerToys Run* Shortcut to something else, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

[image: 1]

Answer (score -1):

In case it helps anyone else, I ran into this using the Logitech MX Keys keyboard and figured out that using the opt|start button with the cmd|alt button and the space bar would launch the system window menu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Power Toys Run was my problem. Turned that off and my problem went away. The smoking gun was that when I used  I got the Power Toys Run dialog popping up, indicating that something else had capture that hot key combination, but I didn't recognize what it was. Left-Alt-space got the pop up. Right-alt-space did nothing. If you have Power Toys, that's probably your problem. If you don't have Power Toys, check to see if you are getting any action at all from Alt-space. If you are, that would indicate that key combo has been reassigned somehow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the question was asked long before PowerToys was available. It's purely due to the use of AltGr in the English International keyboard instead of Alt in the English keyboard and has nothing to do with PowerToys

Comment: Samsung Magician was blocking Alt+Space for me. Exiting it makes it work again. Posting here because of this question being the first hit on Google.