# Why does the Alt+Space keyboard shorcut no longer work on Windows 10 to open the system menu?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently installed Windows Power Toys on my machine and all of a sudden the Alt+Space keyboard shortcut no longer works. It brings up a search feature instead.

Comment: Alt Space is not a general Windows 10 shortcut. It is app specific.  Is the combination not working on any app?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13805/windows-keyboard-shortcuts-in-apps

Comment: @John Alt+Space would bring up the move, resize menu previously.

Comment: Updates have probably changed this.  Not showing up on two V2004 machines and one 20H2 Insider machine, just for apps as posted in the article.

Comment: @John Microsoft says it "Open(s) the shortcut menu for the active window." see "Copy, paste, and other general keyboard shortcuts" at this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to go to the PowerToys Settings > PowerToys Run and disable the feature (at the very top). It is an application launcher built into PowerToys. It is on by default and overrides default system behavior.